# Rails: Comment Model - Connected to a Micropost_id and User_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, comments

**EDIT**

The Routing Error has disappeared thanks to *carlosramireziii* who helped changed the Form to

```
<%= form_for (@micropost) do |f| %>
<%= fields_for :comments do |ff| %>
<%= ff.text_area :content %>
<% end %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But the issue now is that the post will not save, any suggestions?

---

I am currently making a comments model that is connected to a:

`micropost_id :integer` and `user_id :integer`

The problem that I continue to receive is when I post something I get this in return:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/microposts/comments"
```

This is my **routes.eb**

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

This is the **Comment Form**

```
<%= form_for([@micropost, @micropost.comments.new]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This is the **Comment Template**

```
<%= div_for comment do %> 
<div class='UserCommentContainer'>
<div class='UserComment'>
<div class='UserName sm'>
Anonymous
</div>
<div class='UserCommentText'>
<%= comment.content %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And finally this is what is inside the **Micropost**

```
<div id='CommentContainer' class='Condensed2'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%= render "comments/form" %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
<%= render @micropost.comments %>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything else related to the comments model and controller I have posted below, I have been mulling around this for a long time and could really use help, thank you!

**Comments Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :micropost

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :micropost_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'comments.created_at DESC'
end
```

**Micropost Model**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
  has_many :replies, :through => :microposts, :source => :comments
end
```

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create 
    @comment = @micropost.comments.new(params[:comment]) 
    if @comment.save 
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      redirect_to @user
    end 
  end 
end
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.new
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to save a new `comment` on a `micropost` that hasn't been saved yet. Since you have your `comments` routes nested underneath the `microposts` routes, the `micropost` needs to exist before you can create a new comment.

If you want to create both objects in the same form, you need to use nested model attributes.

**Micropost**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :comments do |ff %>
      <%= ff.text_area :content %>
   <% end %>          
   <div class="CommentButtonContainer">
      <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice but when the `<%= f.fields_for :comments do |ff %>
      <%= ff.text_area :content %>
   <% end %> ` is added, the field disappear and I cannot comment

Comment: I actually took out the f in the f.fields_for and the textarea appeared but the comment does not save onto the microposting